# Which AWS service to use to deploy Backend?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a website (static sitting in s3), content is served from s3. I am planning to write a rest api (node or open to suggestions). When the front end makes angular $http call, example  if my site is called example.com, then the call will be something like relative url (/Update) should be resolved.

I am not sure exactly, what type of aws service I should use to deploy my backend code.

**Updated**

I am using Codestar, using Express web service. Here is my template.yml. and routes. The code star build goes fine, but deployment fails.

**template.yml**

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform:
- AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
- AWS::CodeStar

Parameters:
  ProjectId:
    Type: String
    Description: AWS CodeStar projectID used to associate new resources to team members

Resources:
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
        PostEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
  GetItemsBylId:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3
      Role:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Join ['-', [!Ref 'ProjectId', !Ref 'AWS::Region', 'LambdaTrustRole']]
      Events:
        GetEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /api/getItemsBylId/:id
            Method: get
```

Here is my **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send({
    "Output": "Hello World!"
  });
});

app.get('/api/GetItemsBylId/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
      "Output": "I am up!"
    });
});
```

Here is the error from deployment at **GetItemsBylId**

```
   Failed to set tags on AWS::Lambda::Function. IAM permissions lambda:ListTags, lambda:TagResource and lambda:UntagResource are required to tag AWS::Lambda::Function resources and to propagate stack level tags.
```

I am pretty sure it's because of the id param.

**Update**

solved the tag issue using query params. Rather than using, resouce:id, I am now using ?id="".

Comment: Have you considered API Gateway

Comment: You don't deploy backend code on API Gateway. It's used to connect backend code to URL endpoints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple things to consider here:

**[API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)+[Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)**

Lambda is what's often considered a serverless solution. Instead of worrying about underlying infrastructure you simply write out the code and the underlying AWS managed resources run it for you. API gateway integrates with Lambda to allow you to map various REST style URLs to Lambda functions.

Advantages

- For quick calls very cost effective
- Easy integration with AWS services through built in SDKs
- Usage of IAM roles to allow easy access to services without needing to worry about credentials
- A large number of them can be run in parallel for dealing with lots of calls
- Support for a number of languages, NodeJS included
- Don't have to worry about availability zones

Drawbacks

- Limited resources
- Can be somewhat cumbersome dealing with native compiled packages
- A hard limit of 5 minutes. This can make tasks such as dealing with images/video unlikely candidates for usage.
- Disk space is very limited

**[Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)**

An interesting way to utilize EC2 instances to carve them up into containers. Especially nice if you're used to dealing with docker images.

Advantages

- Better methods of dealing with processing large files
- No need to worry about the Lambda timeout
- Ability to carve up EC2 instances to better utilize the full machine resources and get what you pay for

Disadvantages

- Might be difficult to understand if you're not familiar with Docker/Containers
- Still going to be pricier than the Lambda route
- Might want to re-consider if you're going to deal with a high IO type setup
- Possibly having to deal with mapping routes -> services
- You have to be careful that your instances aren't in a single availability zone, essentially bringing all your services down until you can spin new resources up in another availability zone.

**[Elastic Compute (EC2)](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)**

I'd recommend looking into this for the more IO centered workloads. There's a number of available options including provisioned IOPS, Instance Store, high IO instance types, etc.

Advantages

- The most control over the system, and a setup that may be easier for those used to traditional VPS hosting
- A lot easier when you need to deal with custom libraries, native code, various languages
- IAM roles attached to an EC2 instance can be used to allow underlying code easy access to AWS resources
- A number of instance types available for high IO, high bandwidth, and other needs
- A system can be customized, then turned into an AMI to allow for reproducible systems
- May be easier to work with for some than Docker/Container solutions
- Can easily work with load balancers/auto scaling groups to scale up and down as needed, while being able to point to a single endpoint (the load balancer) and not having to worry about

Disadvantages

- Cost is going to be an issue
- Constant monitoring to make sure that your instance types meet your needs and you're not underutilizing what you're paying for
- The pricing model can be a little odd to work with since it's by per hour versus per month. There are however cost estimate calculators that will let you know your monthly estimated cost.
- If you use load balancing (which is ideal) there's additional costs
- Have to consider availability zones in where you place your servers, though Auto Scaling Groups can help with automating that. Still, it's another cost point to consider.
- You get to manage the underlying OS, including updates

**[Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)**

This is a nice interface to the EC2 side of things. Can be useful if you just have code you want to run and would rather something else make most of the decisions on where/how to run it.

Advantages

- Takes away a lot of the guesswork for basic use cases
- Most of the same advantages of what EC2+Load balancing has

Disadvantages

- Since resources are abstracted you need to be a lot more careful on what costs you're incurring
- Can make it a bit more difficult to make modifications to the underlying resources (though at this point you might be at the level where you can manage things without Elastic Beanstalk)

Now regarding the databases you might need to store things:

**[DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)**

A NoSQL data store. If you can get away with storing data as key-value pairs without a lot of relating data with each other then this is nicely priced. The free tier limits are also good.

Advantages

- Straightforward method of managing read/write load
- Very fast
- Has caching available if you need it
- Very nicely priced free tier model

Disadvantages

- Not good for working with structured data with a lot of relationships and the need to query on those relationships
- There are indexes, but you start to pay if you need additional ones
- Might be confusing for those not used to NoSQL
- Over free tier starts to get into hourly and per GB pricing
- A lot easier to find SDK/APIs that deal with popular relational databases

**[SimpleDB](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/)**

Just as the name says a fairly simple DB. This is good for dealing with fairly small workloads or a place to temporarily store data.

Advantages

- Can deal with structured data
- Charges you based on specific time frames of utilization, versus charging you for always on instances like what you would have for EC2
- Free tier is reasonable for small loads

Disadvantages

- Not going to be ideal if you want to store large amounts of data being a 1GB free tier limit
- The pricing model can be a bit confusing
- Not recommended for if you need to go into high read/write workflows
- Probably better to go with the RDS solution if you need structured data and access it pretty much all the time

**[RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)**

What you'd expect for databases that most people are familiar with. Includes MySQL, Aurora (Amazon's customized MySQL), PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL server.

Advantages

- More closely matched with how a lot of folks are used to dealing with databases
- Is better at working with structured data than DynamoDB
- Since it's backed by popular databases, makes it a bit easier for data import/export, especially if you want to check the data locally
- SQL clients are fairly standard in most programming languages so it will be a lot easier to interface with

Disadvantages

- Not as great compared to DynamoDB's free tier
- Can get costly depending on needs
- There's a little bit more involved in tuning IO performance

I think I've touched on the basic advantages and disadvantages but am probably missing some items that the comments section will remind me of after this. I also highly recommend looking over all the linked sites to get a better understanding of the services and what meets your needs, as there's only so much I can drop into this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time & nice explanation. I really appreciate it. I will take Lambda + gateway route probably. I am exploring the costs, since I am in free tier, I hope it won't be much.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information to give you a good answer. It depends on what your backend needs to do and how it needs to scale. If you just need to provide simple functionality AWS Lambda functions are a good, easy, and very cheap way to do it without spinning up an entire EC2 instance. Lambda functions support Node.js (as well as Python, C# & Java).

It's a nice way to try things out without too much of a commitment. The code should be easy to move over to a EC2 instance running Node should you decide you need a more proper server environment or need to do things like write to a filesystem.

It may be easier to host your API on a subdomain i.e. api.example.com rather than under the same domain as your S3 bucket, but if you need them to all be under the same domain you could probably do it by setting up an S3 proxy in the gateway. (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [AWS Codestar](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-codestar/).

Single button push and you will have a fully running CI/CD pipeline and publicly available endpoint for you develop against.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that, running into an issue with Lambda List tag. Updated my questions, can  you please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: figured it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using serverless. I tried codestar also but run into a limitation error

> AWS CodeStar encountered an error while handling your request: One or more policies in IAM could not be created or updated. The number of resources in your project has exceeded the IAM policy size limit.. Try again with different parameters, or contact AWS Support.

Support said there is no workaround I have around 19 functions in my template.yml but when I add more it gives me this error, I have no clue how to fix this, there is no project that can have a maximum of 19 functions.